# Javascript Animate Open/Close Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm working on a simple Open/Close Animate DIV for a webpage I'm building.  It should be simple rather, but something is giving me a hangup.  Heres my JS code:

```
<script>
slideOpen = 1;
alert(slideOpen);

function openClose(){

if (slideOpen = 1){
    closeTab();
    slideOpen = 0;
};
if (slideOpen = 0){
    openTab();
    slideOpen = 1;
};
function closeTab(){
    $("#upcomingEvents").animate({top:"-910px"});
}

function openTab(){
    $("#upcomingEvents").animate({top:"-300px"});
}
alert(slideOpen);
}
</script>
```

And here's the HTML that runs the function:

```
<a href="javascript:openClose();" style="position: absolute; bottom: 32px; right: 32px;" >Open/Close Tab</a>
```

So, the idea behind this was that whenever a user clicks the anchor, it runs the openClose() function.  On initial page load, slideOpen = 1, if a user clicks the anchor, if slideOpen = 1, it runs the closeTab() animation function and then sets slideOpen = 0.  If slideOpen = 0, the openTab() animate function should run and set slideOpen = 1.

Basically:
If tab is open slideOpen = 1;
if tab is closed slideOpen = 0;

However, I've also set two alerts in this function; an initial one on page load, and one that runs every time the openClose() function is called.

On inital page load, slideOpen alert says,"1".  After clicking the anchor to close the tab, slideOpen alert in the openClose() function says, "0" and the tab closes successfully.  Clicking the anchor again, the alert says, "0" again and the tab does not re-open.  It SHOULD display slideOpen = "1", but for some reason it's not.  Therein lies my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey - have you tried https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/ ? it'll automatically keep track of your visible state so you dont have to.

Comment: I may add that later, thanks for showing me.  But, the issue at large is that even my own toggle is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (slideOpen = 1){
```

Here you are assigning 1 to variable `slideOpen`, so the condition will always evaluate to true.

use `==` instead of `=` for both conditions

like

```
if (slideOpen == 1){
```

Comment: Thank you, that is correct, but this only half-fixed my issue.  Now when you click the anchor, the tab animates closed and then immediately opens back up again.  I have not changed anything except the "=" to "==".

Comment: @user2217822 it seems to be working fine.. http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/S24Pz/10/

Comment: @user2217822 Did you do the same for `(slideOpen == 0)`?

Comment: @easwee i had mentioned "for both conditions" in the ans.. :)

Comment: @TilwinJoy yeah - but just checking if he missed that:)

Comment: Yes I've added "==" to both conditions, going to try a boolean instead of 0 and 1

Comment: The "if" statement 'if (slideOpen = 0){' needed to be 'else if (slideOpen = 0){'.  Thanks!

Comment: @user2217822 you're not getting it - your setting it.. use double equals instead of one equals by itself - otherwise you're always going to return true. that could be just "else" and that would evaluate the same way. you're setting slideOpen to 0 IN an if statement criteria.